# Web Browser Screen Resolution / ViewPort width

Tags: chrome-for-android, browser, screen-resolution

I've recently upgraded from a OnePlus 5T to a Oneplus 9 Pro.

I have noticed that when viewing webpages, the viewport width on the 9 Pro is smaller than on the 5T, even though the 9 Pro has a higher screen resolution.

When I visit http://whatismyscreenresolution.net/ on the 5T, it shows 412x823, and on the 9 PRO it shows 384x858.

Is there anyway to 'fix' this so that the 9 Pro has a higher viewport width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed this by changing the 'Display Size' setting in phone settings to 'Small'.

Comment: Upvoted for posting your solution..  Just FYI, you should be able to accept your own answer, although perhaps not immediately.